# How many units and resources will the Germans get when they research logistics?

Tags: civilization-board-game

Is there any official/de facto interpretation for this topic?

> After setup, each time the Germans research a tech that upgrades or unlocks a unit, they build one of that unit for free and gain one resource of their choice from the market."

It seems that this description is ambiguous and I think it can be interpreted as below:

1. They get three units and three resources.
2. They get three units and one resource.
3. They get one unit and one resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not (at least yet) an *official*, explicit statement for this. For the time before a new FAQ version is released, I would suggest to stick into the *[Official and Unofficial rules and clarifications](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/98422/civilization-summary-official-and-unofficial-rules)* made by [Itchi (BGG)](http://boardgamegeek.com/user/Itchi). He was one of the playtesters of the Wisdom & Warfare expansion, and this UFAQ is used in our playgroup if no help is offered by the official rules or the FAQ.

> 87. **Germans get 3 resources and 3 units by researching or learning Logistics** if they havent already unlocked these levels of units. For
>     example, if they already had Democracy and research Logistics, they
>     will gain 2 resources and 2 free units (Mounted and Artillery). For
>     example, if they already have Railroad and Mathematics and learn
>     Logistics, they will gain 2 resources and 2 free units (Infantry and
>     Mounted).

Remember, that this is true also even if you have level 3 or level 4 units unlocked. From the official [FAQ v.2.0](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/civilization/news/Civilization%20FAQ_v2.0.pdf):

> Q: If the Germans research a tech which unlocks a level 3 or 4 unit
> and later researches a tech which unlocks the level 2 unit of the same
> type, do they still get the free unit and resource?
>
> A: Yes